# How to input measurement noise in statsmodels unobserved components model?

Tags: python, statsmodels

I am currently trying to write dlm with statsmodel and pymc3 but I am not sure how is the statsmodel unobserved components model take measurement noise as input? I can give it endogs and exogs but what about the measurement variance?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by measurement noise, but maybe you mean the epsilon term [from the documentation](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.statespace.structural.UnobservedComponents.html).

If so, the variance of that term is a parameter of the model. You can pass a vector of parameters to update the state space system matrices via the `update` method, or you can perform filtering / smoothing via the `smooth` method.